# Limiting what content is displayed from MySQL/ PHP

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm building an interactive timeline that loads in films and calculates the difference between their release dates, thus displaying "days" where there isn't any film release to create a timeline effect. However I have some films that are released on the same date. I don't want to repeat the date for these films over and over again, rather just display the date for the first film in like a group effect.

I have manipulated an `if` statement that loops through the table and checks whether the date is the same as the previous row's date.

http://ignitethatdesign.com/CheckFilm/test_search.php

However how would I use PHP to only display the date for the first film in a group of films with the same date?

I'm using a complex loop system, here is the full code

```
<?php                      
 $last_value = null;
 echo "<div class=\"timeline\">";

$pNumber = 0;
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {

                      if (!is_null($last_value)) {
                          $pNumber++;
                      $a = new DateTime($row['FilmRelease']);
                      $film_date = $row['FilmRelease'];

                      $film_name = urldecode($row['FilmName']);  
                      $film_desc = urldecode($row['Synopsis']);  
                      echo "<div id=\"t".$pNumber."\"><p class=\"everyday\">".$film_name."</div>";


                          if (empty($film_desc)) {
                            echo "<div id=\"b".$pNumber."\" style=\"font-size:12px;\">No film information for ".$film_name."</div>";
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                             echo "<div id=\"b".$pNumber."\"  style=\"font-size:12px;\">".$film_desc."</div>";
                             }

                                    ?> <script type="text/javascript">
                                     $("#b<?php echo $pNumber ?>").hide(); 
                                $("#t<?php echo $pNumber ?>").click(function() {
                                  $("#b<?php echo $pNumber ?>").fadeToggle("slow");
                                });


                                </script>
                                <?php
                                  $interval = $a->diff(new DateTime($last_value));
                                  //echo $interval->format('%d days');
                                  $b = new DateTime($last_value);
                                  $i = 0;
                                } 

                                if ($b == $a)
                                {
                                    echo "same date as above";
                                } else 
                                {
                                    echo "This date is different";
                                }

                        $howManydays = $interval->days;

                        for ( $i; $i < $howManydays; $i++) {
                            echo "<p class=\"day\"></p>";


                        }

              $last_value = $row['FilmRelease'];
            } 
            echo "<div id=\"end\"></end>";
            echo "</div>";

            ?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: This would depend on how your data is structured - but you've not shown us what your data looks like. (order the data by date, and only write the date when it changes)

Answer (score 0):

Simple example:

```
$lastDate = null;

while (...) {
    $currentDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($film['date']));
    if ($currentDate != $lastDate) {
        echo "<h1>$currentDate</h1>";
    }
    $lastDate = $currentDate;

    // output film details
}
```

This will give you something like:

```
2012-04-01

Film A
Film B

2012-04-02

Film C

2012-04-05

Film D
Film E
```

Comment: Hi, i have that working in the form off - if ($b == $a)
                                {
                                    echo "same date as above";
                                } else 
                                {
                                    echo "This date is different";
                                }

I want to only echo out the first result in a group that has the same film date though

Comment: its nearly perfect how come it is missing out certain information, (every line that hasnt got a date on is meant to be a day difference)